# Can I reuse the same .onion address if my server uptime is intermittent?

Tags: onion-services

I want to run a small hobby server over the Tor network and be able to share the onion address with my friends. The server reachability will be intermittent. Can I keep using the same onion address?

Note: I am aware that uptime tracking can be used to isolate my server if it goes up and down and thus is a deanonymization threat. At this point this is not a concern for this project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.
Your hidden service's onion address is generated based on your hidden service's public key, so as long you keep that the same your onion address will stay the same.